# boost::stacktrace::frame::name() hangs

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I am trying to retrieve a stack trace in my program, and store it for later use (debugging purposes). But the call to boost::stacktrace::frame::name() never returns, and I have no clue why. When I use this exact code in a simple project, it runs nicely. Any ideas?

```cpp
    boost::stacktrace::stacktrace stacktrace;
    stringstream stacktraceText;
    for (const auto& entry : stacktrace)
    {
        if (entry.empty() == false)
        {
            auto name = entry.name();
            stacktraceText  << name << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            stacktraceText += L"<missing symbol info>\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*But the call to `boost::stacktrace::frame::name()` never returns*" - cannot reproduce on GCC 8.2.0. Currently I have no access to MSVS, but it may be helpful to inspect the implementation of `boost::stacktrace::frame::name()`. Implementation that I have access to simply returns an empty `std::string` if any of the macros `BOOST_WINDOWS` nad `__CYGWIN__` is undefined. Did you debug the call? If no, why? If yes, what did the debugging process show?

Comment: Works with VS2019 in a simple main for me. I don't see where `std::stringstream` has a `+=` operator, btw. There must be more to this.